# Fetch api not posting data to backend server

Tags: azure, react-native, express, fetch-api, face-api

I am using cognitive service by azure which I am using Face API, In frontend the user will take picture then will call the API to check if face detected or not after that face id will be added using  `Add Face under FaceList` as in azure documentation, after that I want to update column in database if face added successfully, here i am calling a function called `senddata()` which will use fetch API to send data to backend server then in server the database column will be updated, the problem is after face added successfully the senddata() function is not posting any data to backend server:
here is the code of taking picture:

```
 const takePicture = async () => {
        if (camera) {
            const data = await camera.current.takePictureAsync({ quality: 0.25, base64: true });
            const selfie_ab = base64ToArrayBuffer.decode(data.base64);
           
            setTakingPic(true)

            try {
                const facedetect_instance_options = { ...base_instance_options };
                facedetect_instance_options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
                const facedetect_instance = axios.create(facedetect_instance_options);

                const facedetect_res = await facedetect_instance.post(
                    `/detect?returnFaceId=true&detectionModel=detection_02`,
                    selfie_ab
                );

                console.log("face detect res: ", facedetect_res.data);

                if (facedetect_res.data.length) {

                    const add_face_instance_options = { ...base_instance_options };
                    add_face_instance_options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
                    const add_face_instance = axios.create(add_face_instance_options);
                    const addface_res = await add_face_instance.post(
                        `/facelists/${facelist_id}/persistedFaces`, selfie_ab
                    );

                    if (addface_res.data.persistedFaceId.length) {
                        const status = "on hold";
                        const faceid = addface_res.data.persistedFaceId;
                        senddata(status, faceid)
                        console.log("Face add and send for approval: ", addface_res.data.persistedFaceId);
                    } else {
                        Alert.alert("error", "something went wrong");
                    }

                } else {
                    Alert.alert("error", "Detection failure. Please make sure there is sufficient light when taking a selfie");
                }

            } catch (err) {
                console.log("err: ", err);
            }

        }
    };
```

here the `senddata()` function:

```
 const senddata = (status, faceid) => {
        console.log(status)
        console.log(faceid)
        fetch('http://*********/users/updateRegStatus', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: status,
                faceid: faceid
            })
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
             
                if (res.success === true) {
                    alert(res.message);
                    navigation.navigate('dashboard')
                }
                else {

                    alert(res.message);

                }
            })

    }
```

and the following code form the backend which for updating the database:

```
router.post('/updateRegStatus', function (req, res, next) {

  var status = req.body.status;
  var faceid = req.body.faceid;
 

  connection.query("INSERT INTO face_status (status,faceid) VALUES (?,?) ", [status, faceid], function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send({ 'success': true, 'message': 'Your face details sent for approval' });
    }
  });
});
```

pleaser help me

Comment: Could you please check if your backed server has received your request?

Comment: @JimXu no the server isn't receiving the request